# Access text on a website using a Javascript injection

Tags: javascript, html, web, code-injection

I want to access particular bits of text on a website, using a javascript injection.

Going through the HTML however, i find that most of it is lacking Id's, and so i do not know how to access the text.

For example, two lines of the HTML are the following:

```
<td valign="top" width="100%" >
<h1>My example heading</h1>
```

Would there still be any way of finding out what this text says?

Also, if DO know what that text says, is there any way of finding out the following bit of text...

```
<td valign="top" width="100%" >
<h1>You are trying to work out:</h1>
<h1>This text</h1>
```

Comment: Not likely. Without id's, it will be hard to home in on the nodes you're trying to get to.  You could get fancy with some regular expressions, or try some server-side screen-scraping, but those solutions break pretty easily.

Comment: what if a large proportion of the page is always the same. It is simply particular details that are different. Say, a report is being shown, with different statistics each time, which i want to get details of.

Comment: then I'd say you stand a fairly good chance of being able to pinpoint the tags you need by collecting them with .getElementsByTagName("h1") and iterating through collection that gets returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, that's not too bad at all. You'll want to do something like this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
var text1 = "";
var text2 = "";
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].width == "100%" && els[i].getAttribute("valign") == "top") {
        var h1s = els[i].getElementsByTagName("h1");
        if (h1s.length > 0) text1 = h1s[0].innerHTML;
        if (h1s.length > 1) text2 = h1s[1].innerHTML;
    }
}
```

Now, if there were lots of tables, you might need to replace the first line with this:

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[2].getElementsByTagName("tr")[4].getElementsByTagName("td");
```

Read that as: Get table elements, select the third one. Get all of that table's rows, select the fifth one. Get all that row's cells. Look for any ones with 100% width and valigned top, and see if they've got h1's.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JUK5R/26/

Comment: Wow... Thankyou heaps :)
And answered a few other questions i had while you were at it :D

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sure thing! :) jQuery's so popular these days it's easy to overlook the "old fashioned" way.

Comment: Quick question, how can you make sure that the h1 that you are getting is within the td? I can't seem to work out how that would work. Not sure whether your code above does or not, but it appears that the for loops achieves nothing as the h1's are found in such a way that is unaffected by the results of the search.

Comment: oh shoot, my apologies! fixed.

(Basically, call getElementsByTagName on the element whose children you're searching for. So once you've found the td, els[i], call getEle... on that.)

Comment: haha thanks, had me a bit boggled there, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 3):

It's really dependent on the page.

For instance, if you are always interested in the 3rd H1 then you can (example with JQuery, but it is as easy to do it without):

```
h1s = $("h1");
myh1 = h1s[2];
```

If, however, the page is dinamycally generated you will have to find some reproducible way to always get to your element (e.g. get the table with id xxx, go through the rows until you find one with the text yyy, and take the 2nd div child element).

This, more likely than not, will not work 100% of the times... but there is no other solution really.

**EDIT**: for instance, to do what I said above you could do

```
// Get all the tds of the table with id tableid
table = $("#tableid td");

// Go through the td
for (var i=0; i<tds.length; i++)
    {
    // If the content of the cell matches some pattern
    if ($(rows[i]).text().match(/somestring/))
        {
        // Get the span children of the td
        divchildren = $(rows[i]).children("span");
        // Take the 2nd
        requiredText = $(divchildren[1]).text();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hoping i won't get the reply of "Go learn javascript basics first" here, but I am totally new to javascript, and am currently learning it. Any quick pointers on where to look/what to do, to search through as you said "get the table with id xxx, go through the rows until you find one with the text yyy, and take the 2nd div child element" ? Thanks

Comment: And wouldn't that return the 4th h1 ?